# Problem on string vibration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Given the standard wave equation for small amplitudes, we have been asked to find the position of string $y(x,t)$, given:

1. $y(x,0)=\sin x$, and,
2. $y'(x,0)=\cos x$, where $y'$ depicts partial derivative of $y$ wrt $t$.

Please, someone help me realise the situation, and supply a solution to this problem, as well.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184355/2451

Answer (score 0):

The argument of a moving wave will be of the form $\omega(t- \frac xv)$, where $ \omega$ is the time frequency and $v$ is velocity.

$$Y(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$

Insert into the wave equation:

$$X''T=\frac{XT''}{v^2}$$

Where $X''$ and $T''$ are derivatives wrt to their own variable. Rearrange:

$$\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T''}{v^2T}=-\omega^2$$

where $-\omega^2$ is the constant of separation. Since both sides are functions of only one variable, we can treat both sides as ordinary differential equations.

$$X=\{\sin(\omega \ x),\cos(\omega \ x) \}$$

$$T=\{\sin(\omega\ v\ t),\cos(\omega\  v\ t) \}$$

$Y$ will be a linear combination of these linearly independent solutions

$$Y=A\sin(\omega \ x)\sin(\omega\ v\ t)+B\sin(\omega \ x)\cos(\omega\  v\ t)\\ +C\cos(\omega \ x)\sin(\omega\ v\ t)+D\cos(\omega \ x)\cos(\omega\  v\ t)  $$

It is clear that we have $\omega=1$

At $t=0$ we have $Y=\sin x$ so $D=0$ and $B=1$

At $t=0$ we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}Y=vA\sin x \cos vt + \sin x \sin vt+ vC\cos x \cos vt=\cos x$$

so we get $C=\frac1v$ and $A=0$

the result is

$$Y=\sin x \cos vt + \frac1v \cos x \sin vt$$

Comment: please supply me with a solution to the problem..

Comment: $y=sin(t+x)$ Which means the wave is traveling in the (-) direction. They must have taught you this.

Comment: i am requesting you to provide me with a solution through the use of technique of variable separation as used in solving partial differential equations, as is done in case of Laplace equation, in case of temperature problems

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#General_solution

Comment: if you want a more specific way of solving it, tell me the formula you are allowed to use

Comment: laplacian(u(x,t))=v^(-2)*u"(x,t), " stands for partial derivative of u wrt t, twice

Comment: @abstract ok, I wrote it